# How to monitor for MySQL select queries that return too many records?

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-5.7, logs, alerts

I realize there are simple ways to limit results in SQL. I have a legacy implementation. I would like to get a handle on select queries that return **results exceeding some user defined limit**. The **goal** would be to have better insights to the kind of queries sent to the database. Some of these queries can translate into performance issues in the code that processes the results and/or excessive heap consumption.  To gain insights, I'd like to **monitor** a **production** databases with a **log entry** for any query exceeding a threshold. Configuring an **alarm/alert** would even be better. The solution needs to be one that can be deployed to production. I'm not looking for a QA or Performance tool solution.

Comment: is slow query log sufficent for your needs? Set `long_query_time` to the threshold.

Comment: @danblack Unfortunately it's not. The database performance is fine. It's what happens in the server code that consumes it.

Comment: [sys schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema.html) or the rawer version of [performance schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema.html) might provide you some insights you need.

Comment: Number of rows probably isn't the best performance metric to measure and throttle, at least not by itself. Firstly because usually any performance issues aren't directly correlated to the number of rows being returned, rather they're due to concurrency issues, poor written queries (e.g. I can write a query that only returns 1 row but brings your server to a crawl because of the Tables it needs to access to find that 1 row and the operations needed to process the query), improper indexing and/or database architecture, or under-provisioned and/or incorrectly configured server instance. Second...

Comment: ...there's no generally proactive way to limit the number of rows returned from an individual query by a certain threshold until after all the work has already been done to process & locate those records, unless you just do a blanket limit on all queries or review logs of past slow queries & put a blanket threshold on those individual type of queries. But again you may end up limiting a performant query that was previously slow due to other server contention not due to the # of rows. Thirdly, it won't be easy to ensure data accuracy by limiting random rows, unless you have a common sort field.

Comment: @J.D. the goal isn't to Limit. It's to know about queries that return more than n rows with a log or an alert. It can be a critical metric for a host.  The performance of the query can be fine, but in our case it resulted in the JVM consuming all its heap because of the knock off effect when consuming the results. The query that caused our problem wasn't among the slow queries.

Comment: @Lifehouse Sorry, it just sounded like that was your end goal when you said "*I realize there are simple ways to limit results in SQL*". Without more context I don't fully follow how the JVM is at play here, but I assume you mean a Java application that is receiving the results of these queries in some capacity, and that is where your issue is occuring? If so, that sounds like something that should be corrected in the application layer as opposed the database later. If you have access to the application, it should be analyzed for potentially problematic queries, and logging & error handling...

Comment: ...should be occuring inside there, to catch any *data overload*. I did see you mentioned *hosting*, so not sure if you mean that you guys host JVM applications and their correlating databases for multiple users, and so your internal monitoring on an individual application is limited then. If so, even then I'd imagine you should have monitoring tools on each hosted JVM & they shouldn't step on each other. If within a single individual instance, a users application goes down because of their poor design, then the onus should be on them not you. But this is all speculation without more context.

Comment: @J.D. I understand and agree. Ultimately the problem needs to be resolved in the application. While the db may return efficiently a large result, the consumer may not. There typically is a performance correlation between small and large result sets. My goal is to surface results we determine as large to explore the code sending the request and consuming the response. There may be some performance improvement opportunities. It's another way for us to monitor for anomalies.  It's very old code. It surfaced for the first time with a unique set of user inputs.

Comment: @Lifehouse Gotcha, I guess the 5 second version of my previous rant lol, is if this has been an issue already, wouldn't you have the call stack from when the error was thrown within the application layer, and should be able to debug the source? And would it be simple enough to add a global error handler to the suspect application (that gracefully logs or emails you the exception), even just in the interim? (I haven't worked with Java since my college days, mostly work in C# now, but I would assume these are general programmatic concepts that apply in most procedural languages.)

Answer (score 1):

### SUGGESTION #1 : STATUS VARIABLES

You could check the status variable

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_rows_read';
```

or read it from the performance_schema

```
SELECT variable_value FROM performance_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_rows_read';
```

You could see other row metrics as well:

```
mysql> select version(); show global status like 'InnoDB_rows%';
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.26    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name        | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| Innodb_rows_deleted  | 0     |
| Innodb_rows_inserted | 0     |
| Innodb_rows_read     | 8     |
| Innodb_rows_updated  | 0     |
+----------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

### SUGGESTION #2 : SLOW LOG

If you need to see the number of rows returned or examined by any given query, you will need to enable the slow query log.

Here is an example of a slow log entry that sees a mysqldump in progress

```
# Time: 150419  6:00:43
# User@Host: web[web] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 7.730519  Lock_time: 0.000070 Rows_sent: 167620  Rows_examined: 167620
SET timestamp=1429416043;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `messages`;
```

As shown, the number of rows returned and examined are in the header.

Comment: These are excellent recommendations for post mortem analysis. How would you recommend to continually monitor the slow log?